# MySQL query : Finding related attributes

Tags: mysql

I am a bit new to MySQL and trying my hands on learning it. However I got stuck with an query that goes as follows:
I have 2 tables: Table 1 contains details of lists created by a user. The fields are listid, listname, creatorid, createdat,membercount;
Table 2 stores data of members  of each list: The fields are listid, userid;

The query I need to process is as follows: Find out all the pairs of users of the form (u1,u2) where both of the following conditions are satisfied
i. u1 has created at least one list and u2 is a member of that list.
ii. u2 has created at least one list and u1 is a member of that list.

Note: listid in the table 2 is the foreign key for listid in table 1.

Comment: @Luiggi I have been able to select the required attributes from the two table using INNER JOIN however dont know what condition to use to get the desired tuple after WHERE clause.

Comment: have you learned about nested queries? they have this form: `select t1.a, t3.b from table t1, (select c from t2 where t2.a = t1.a) t3 where t3.c = t1.c`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza My actual query consisted of 2 parts (pse refer to edited question). For the first part Niko's solution was ok. But when I try to use a nested query for both parts I lad into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT l.creatorid AS u1, u.userid AS u2
FROM table2 AS u
INNER JOIN table1 AS l ON l.listid = u.listid
```

Returns every user from Table2 and the ID of the creator of the corresponding list.

Comment: he needs the id of list creator and the ids of the users who are members in that list

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what this query selects.

Comment: what if you have user1 as creator of list1 and user2 as a member of list1, while table2 has user1, user2 and user3?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza As I have understood I need to run following nested queries:

Comment: (get all members of a list(find the lists of each member(check if list_creator is a member of list created by each member)))